# Get the value of the ASP.NET Identity 2.0 cookie in same request as signin

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-identity-2

When using cookie authentication in ASP.NET MVC, after calling `PasswordSignInAsync` to log the user in, a cookie with encrypted session information is stored for future requests. By default this is named `.AspNet.ApplicationCookie`. Is there a way to get the value of that cookie immediately after signing the user in, before leaving the method that it was called from?

I've inspected `Response.Cookies` after successful sign in, but it doesn't contain any values and I can't figure out when that cookie is actually being set.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

No, you can't get the value of that cookie in the same request as where the cookie is set - the setting is delayed until very late, when the reply is actually sent.

But the cookie is encrypted and not much you can do with the value anyway. I suspect you want to add data to the cookie, but there are better ways to do it, without having to modify cookie itself.

Comment: I didn't want to add anything to it, actually wanted to pass the user's session to another domain which is running the same site. I ended up finding another way to handle this by using a link to switch domains but thanks for the answer.

Answer (score 1):

I discovered that it is possible to intercept the value of the cookie before returning the response, although not in the same method as the signin like I was originally hoping for.

The following code needs to be added in the ConfigureAuth method:

```
const string applicationCookieName = ".AspNet.ApplicationCookie";

app.UseCookieAuthentication(new CookieAuthenticationOptions
{
    AuthenticationType = DefaultAuthenticationTypes.ApplicationCookie,
    LoginPath = new PathString("/"),
    CookieName = applicationCookieName,
    Provider = new CookieAuthenticationProvider
    {
        // Called *after* user is signed in -- the cookie
        // we want has been set at this point.
        OnResponseSignedIn = context =>
        {
            var cookies = context.Response.Headers.GetCommaSeparatedValues("Set-Cookie");
            var cookieValue = "";

            foreach (var cookie in cookies)
            {
                var cookieKeyIndex = cookie.IndexOf(applicationCookieName);
                if (cookieKeyIndex != -1)
                {
                    // Add extra character for '='
                    cookieValue = cookie.Substring(applicationCookieName.Length + 1);
                    break;
                }
            }
            // Do what you need with cookieValue
        }
    }
});
```